# Is there a built-in way to change the style without reloading the whole map?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Whenever I use map.setStyle to change the style, the entire map reloads. This can be seen in the Mapbox GL JS example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/setstyle/

I'm interested in changing the map more seamlessly. An example of this can be seen in Google maps when you switch between Map and Satellite views.

Does Mapbox GL JS have an easy way of style changing without reloading the whole map, or does this need to be implemented manually (I.e. with map.removeSource, map.addSource, map.removeLayer, map.addLayer)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit what you mean by "reloading the whole map". In this case, every single layer and source is being replaced wholesale, so it doesn't really have much choice.

If you have a style object, make some changes to it, and call `setStyle()` with the new style object, my understanding is that only the differences will be acted on. So usually, the effect won't be "reloading the whole map".